# Extracting value from an object

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot, using discord.js.

I've been working on this command for too long without finding a solution, so I come here to ask for help.
Here is my problem, maybe it's really simple to solve to you, and that would be great :D
I want to create a command that sends a random gif, based on a keyword.
I'm using a node module called giphy-random.

```
        (async () => {
            const API_KEY = "hidden";

            const gif = await giphyRandom(API_KEY, {
                tag: "kawaii"
            });
            console.log(gif)
          }
```

I would like to be able to get only the value 'url' of the const which is defined by the function (i'm maybe wrong in my words, I'm a beginner) in order to send it in a channel.

[image: Here is my console log]

Comment: you want `gif.data.url`

Comment: Read about [JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: Thanks you guys for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply want `gif.data.url` In fact if you change your `console.log` like this:

```
console.log(gif.data.url);
```

You'll see the url printed to the console.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/giphy-random#return), the link is returned in `data.url` property of the resulting object. So your code should look like:

```
      (async () => {
        const API_KEY = "hidden";

        const gif = await giphyRandom(API_KEY, {
            tag: "kawaii"
        });
        console.log(gif.data.url)
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply access field like this:

```
            const API_KEY = "hidden";

            const gif = await giphyRandom(API_KEY, {
                tag: "kawaii"
            });

           const {url} = gif.data; // equal to const url = gif.data.url

            console.log(gif);
          }
```